# Reading and Handling Streams

Tags: java, sockets, streamreader

I want to read and handle a stream of String containing single OR multiple commands in one line.

I am currently using `InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();` for my inputstream.

Also for handling the input a typical Thread:

```
public void run() {
    String input = "";
    try {
        int data = 0;
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            while ((data = in.read()) != -1 && !isInterrupted()) {
                input += Integer.toHexString(data);
                handleInput(input);
            }
            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        socket.close();
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        main.log("Connection lost...");
        main.log(e.toString());
        main.stopBTCommunication();
        main.startBTServer();
    }
}
```

`handleInput()` is designed to handle any String given to it and response correctly. The problem with this implementation would be, that `handleInput()` is called with every byte read from `in.read()`. I know, that i could use `BufferedReader.readLine()`, but that would require every incomming command to have `"\n"` appended to it, which is NOT the case and can't be changed.

I know that

```
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            while ((data = in.read()) != -1 && !isInterrupted()) {
```

is kind of nuisance, but basically it want the Thread to read until nothing new is read, then handle that input and then read again...

EDIT:

So basically, what i need is a non-blocking `read()`.

EDIT2:

How can incoming commands and commandchains look like:

- Select Command: "s"
- ReadLine Command: "rlXX" whereby X is a Hex Digit
- WriteLine Command: "wlXXSSSSSSSS" whereby X and S are Hex Digits

So a commandschain may look like one of the following:

- `"s"`
- `"srlff"` = `"s" + "rlff"`
- `"rlffwlbb2e2e2e2erlbb"` = `"s" + "rlff" + "wlbb2e2e2e2e" + "rlbb"`

Comment: So how many bytes do you want to read before calling handleInput? If you want non blocking IO, there are classes in nio package for that purpose.

Comment: until no more bytes are read.

Comment: No more bytes as in until stream is closed or whatever that's available so far? If it's the latter, you can read in an array of bytes and convert that array of bytes to HEX string and then call handleInput().

Comment: As in whatever is available so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read in array of bytes like this

```
int bytesRead = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // reads up to 1024 byte chunks
while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++ ) {
        input += Integer.toHexString(buffer[i]);
    }

    handleInput(input);
}
```

The above code calls is the same as your old code that "input" keeps growing and used over and over again to call handleInput(). No sure if this is your intention but it looks suspicious.

Comment: @hanno binder thanks for the edit. Is it possible to upvote edits? I would do so in an instant :).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you really need a non-blocking read. You need a method that reads the stream byte by byte and translates it into commands as it goes.

Something like:

```
 public void processStream(InputStream in) {
     List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<Command>();
     while((int c = in.getChar()) != -1 ) {
          switch((char)c) {
              case 's':
                  commands.add(new SelectCommand());
                  break;
              case 'r':
                  commands.add(ReadCommand.buildFromStream(in));
                  break;
              case 'w':
                  commands.add(WriteCommand.buildFromStream(in));
                  break;
              case ';':
                  commandEngine.execute(commands);
                  break;
              default:
                  throw new StreamParseError("unexpected character: " + c);
          }
     }
 }
```

This assumes that `SelectCommand`, `ReadCommand`, `WriteCommand` are type-compatible with `Command`.

... with for example ReadCommand.buildFromStream being:

```
   public static ReadCommand buildFromStream(InputStream in) {
        if((char)in.read() != 'n') {
            throw new StreamParseError("Expect 'l' after 'r'");
        }

        // bad error checking here - be less lazy in real life.
        String hexNum = in.read() + in.read(); 
        int num = Integer.parseInt(hexNum,16);
        return new ReadCommand(num);
   }
```

This is very primitive parsing, but it shows the principle. There are well established techniques for more advanced parsing, which you can read up on if you want to.

You could also use a `Scanner`. Most commonly, Scanner is used with delimiters, but it can also look for regex patterns.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);
    String cmd = "";
    while(cmd != "e") { // I made up an "end" command :)
        cmd = scanner.findWithinHorizon("(s|rl..|wl.{8}|e)",12);
        if(cmd == null) {
            // end of input, or badly formed input
            break;
        }
        handleCmd(cmd);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - With this particular input/output, since you don't have a delimiter, Scanner may not be the way to go here, but if you've got a delimiter between commands, it would be a great option, so I'll keep the answer here in the hopes it might help someone in the future.

Since your example doesn't have a delimiter, I have to get a little bit hack-y to demonstrate scanner's awesomeness, but it should still work for the exact commands you've listed. It would not be a good choice if you expect the command vocabulary to change.

I'd really recommend the use of delimiters if at all possible. It makes life much easier.

---

I'd look at the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#delimiter%28%29) class if I were you.

The `Scanner` can wrap your input stream, and then scan based on a regex or delimter to grab chunks of input. Then your `handleInput()` method can operate on chunks (whole commands) rather than individual bytes.

Here's a brief, standalone example:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q22199860;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadStream
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pattern commandPattern = Pattern.compile("s|rl|wl");
        String commands = "srlffwlbb2e2e2e2erlbb";
        Charset utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        try (
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(commands.getBytes(utf8));
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, utf8.name());
        ) {
            scanner.useDelimiter(commandPattern);
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                String command = scanner.next();
                if (command.isEmpty()){
                    //s
                    System.out.println("s" + command);
                } else if (command.length() == 2) {
                    //rl
                    System.out.println("rl" + command);
                } else if (command.length() == 10) {
                    //wl
                    System.out.println("wl" + command);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error Reading Stream");
        }
    }
}
```

The output from this is:

```
s
rlff
wlbb2e2e2e2e
rlbb
```

Comment: Hmm but this would require the commands to be delimited.. which also they are not... commands may come in as `"command1"` or `"command1command2command3"` i will later filter them out with regex.

Comment: How do you know when you've read in a command if there's no delimiter? Do you just read characters until it matches a known command? An example input and the expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the example input/output. That will greatly help people get an answer for you. I've updated my answer, and it should work for the specific example you provided, but it's a bit of a hack using a scanner without a good delimiter - In your case I'd probably try something else. I'm out of time to help for the moment - good luck!

Comment: WoW This works really nice, except for it missing the last entry and providing it with the next push.. like when i send `"srlffwlbb2e2e2e2erlbb"` im getting `"s" + "rlff" + "wlbb2e2e2e2e"` and then when sending `"srlffwlbb2e2e2e2erlbb"` again i get `"rlbb" + "s" + "rlff" + "wlbb2e2e2e2e"`

Comment: Torhan, the "missing last entry" is because "scanner.hasNext()" waits for the next delimiter - and since I'm using the command prefix as a delimiter, it actually waits for the next command to come in before giving you the text in between (and in fact, I'm determining which command it is solely by the number of characters in between commands). Like I said, this method is a bit of a hack :). In my example, it puts everything out at once because it hits the end of the stream, and that kicks out the last command as well.  slim's answer would solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are reading data from a *stream*. This means that you will have to implement recovery of the commands' structure yourself, i.e. you must at least detect the beginning and end of a command in your own code.

This again leads to another problem: You have no guarantee about how your stream's data is split into "chunks" by the transport layer. You may receive one command plus half a command in one `read(buffer)` call and then the second half of the command plus some more data in the next `read(buffer)`.

Therefore, what I recommend is that you keep reading data only until you detect the end of one message/command/whatever and then perform handling for only this single message, before reading more incoming data and repeating. Everything else (i.e. dealing with partially received messages) easily becomes messy.

Comment: Thats exactly what i am trying to achieve. Basically what i am hoping for is a `read()` that returns either the read byte, or -1 on EOS or -2 on nothing to read in Stream..

Comment: [InputStream.available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) could achieve this, but I doubt this is really what you want. Have a look at setting up the socket's [timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29), quote: "With this option set to a non-zero timeout, a read() call on the InputStream associated with this Socket will block for only this amount of time. If the timeout expires, a java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised, though the Socket is still valid."